# c# - how to merge images in vertical?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, captcha

I have this code but doesn't work.I'm trying to extract a image from a site that contains a captcha.

```
        var width = Images.First().Image.Width; //all images in list have the same width so i take the first
        var height = 0;
        for (int i = 104; i < 140; i++) //the list has 300 images. I have to get 36 that contains the captcha separated into pieces
        {
            height += Images[i].Image.Height; 
        }
        var bitmap2 = new Bitmap(width, height);
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap2);

        height = 0;
        for (int i = 104; i < 140; i++)  
        {
            Image image = Images[i].Image;
            g.DrawImage(image, 0, height);
            height += image.Height;
        }

        bitmap2.Save(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

With this code i get this result:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYzTe.png)

I don't know why it is of poor quality. I think it is repeating the images that are recorded in the result bitmap

Comment: g.DrawImage does support "GraphicUnits". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphicsunit?view=netframework-4.8 is there a difference with other units used?

Comment: @SvenBardos to test this i have to set a point[] array that i dont know how, but i think the graphic unit doesnt make difference

Comment: another idea: is it g.DrawImage(image, 0, height -1); ? Because drawing from 0/0 with height e.g. 10 will give you an image from 0/0;x/9 Of course for the first iteration height should then be initialized with 1

Comment: @SvenBardos already tried height-1 and the result is the same

Comment: ALWAYS put a `using` around your graphics object, so it gets properly closed off before you try to save the image.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few suboptimal things in the code, but, to be honest, not a single thing that can give that result. The only way you get problems like that is if you go messing with the raw back-end and perform operations that mess up how the data is interpreted as image.

The only two specific things that need fixing in the code seem to be:

- Setting the resolution of all images to the same values. This affects how large they are drawn, and thus can mess up positioning
- Closing the `Graphics` object after you're done with it, so all changes are confirmed to be finished before you attempt to save anything.

Note that in my adjusted code, `images` is just a `List<Bitmap>`, and the for-loop just goes over them all. You never specified what type your `Images` collection was, and this was much easier for me to test.

```
Int32 width = Images.First().Width;
Int32 height = 0;
for (Int32 i = 0; i < Images.Count; i++)
{
    height += Images[i].Height;
}
Bitmap bitmap2 = new Bitmap(width, height);
bitmap2.SetResolution(72, 72); // <-- Set explicit resolution on bitmap2
// Always put Graphics objects in a 'using' block.
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap2))
{
    height = 0;
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < Images.Count; i++)
    {
        Bitmap image = Images[i];
        image.SetResolution(72, 72); // <-- Set resolution equal to bitmap2
        g.DrawImage(image, 0, height);
        height += image.Height;
    }
}
bitmap2.Save(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```